# Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.TreeView w/ Selection="Multiple", where is the checkbox selected/unselected event?

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

I am using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.TreeView along w/ Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.TreeViewItem with Selection="Multiple".

```xml
<TreeView Name="DessertTree" SelectionMode="Multiple" ItemsSource="{x:Bind DataSource}" ItemInvoked="{x:Bind OnSelectionChanged, Mode=OneTime}">
    <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:DataType="local:Item">
            <TreeViewItem ItemsSource="{x:Bind Children}" Content="{x:Bind Name}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
</TreeView>
```

I cannot seem to find a way to have an event fired for a state change of the checkbox associated with the TreeViewItem. Does anyone have any information on this? I see that the TreeView in WPF has a trigger for change of the checkbox state, so I would think the same functionality is available.

The only trigger I found that is somewhat similar is ItemInvoked, but that does not register selection events on the checkbox, only if the label is clicked.

Comment: Has your issue been solved? If yes, you could mark useful answers to help others that face the same question.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to handle the `Tapped` event for the `TreeViewItem`, find the `CheckBox` in the visual tree and examine its `IsChecked` property:

```
private void OnTreeViewItemTapped(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    TreeViewItem tvi = (TreeViewItem)sender;
    CheckBox chk = FindVisualChild<CheckBox>(tvi);
    bool? isChecked = chk.IsChecked;
}

private static T FindVisualChild<T>(DependencyObject visual) where T : DependencyObject
{
    for (int i = 0; i < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(visual); i++)
    {
        DependencyObject child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(visual, i);
        if (child != null)
        {
            T correctlyTyped = child as T;
            if (correctlyTyped != null)
                return correctlyTyped;

            T descendent = FindVisualChild<T>(child);
            if (descendent != null)
                return descendent;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```